# Emailing Google Sheet as PDF

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script

I have this script that emails me a PDF of the Google Spreadsheet. I only want it to email me the first 'Tab' and if possible as a single PDF vice a zip file.

Wondered if anyone could help. Also one of the 'Tabs' are hidden, so I don't know if that has an impact.  He is a link to the sample [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ep2bIKYux2jFag1oa3mhADRtOUwzlcyIAafdFTODi9A/edit?usp=sharing).

The code is shown below:

```
/* Send Spreadsheet in an email as PDF, automatically */
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {

// Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var email = "xxxxx@gmail.com"; 

  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  // Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Subject of email message
  var subject = "Sample Sheet " + ss.getName(); 

  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  var body = "Install the <a href='http://www.labnol.org/email-sheet'>Email Spreadsheet add-on</a> for one-click conversion.";

  // Base URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=false'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 

  //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
  var blobs = [];

  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {

    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(sheets[i].getName() + '.pdf');

  }

  //create new blob that is a zip file containing our blob array
  var zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs).setName(ss.getName() + '.zip'); 

  //optional: save the file to the root folder of Google Drive
  DriveApp.createFile(zipBlob);

  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments:[zipBlob]     
    });  
}


//**************************************************************************
//                                 Revised Code
//**************************************************************************


/* Send Spreadsheet in an email as PDF, automatically */
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {

// Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var email = "xxxxx@gmail.com"; 

  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  // Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Subject of email message
  var subject = "PDF generated from spreadsheet " + ss.getName(); 

  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  var body = "Install the <a href='http://www.labnol.org/email-sheet'>Email Spreadsheet add-on</a> for one-click conversion.";

  // Base URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=false'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 

  //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
  var blobs = [];

  //for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
  for (var i=0; i<1; i++) {  
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
   // blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(sheets[i].getName() + '.pdf');

  }

  //create new blob that is a zip file containing our blob array
 // var zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs).setName(ss.getName() + '.zip'); 

  //optional: save the file to the root folder of Google Drive
  //DriveApp.createFile(zipBlob);

  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      //attachments:[zipBlob]     
    });  
}
```

Kind Regards
Al

Comment: Your code seem to be work fine, what error are you getting?

Comment: Yes the code works as is but what I want to achieve is only e-mail the 'Front' tab and e-mail it as a PDF vice a zipped file. Currently a zipped file gets e-mailed with 2 PDFs (1 for eachTab). I just want a single PDF to be emailed of the first tab. Kind regards AliG

Answer (score 4):

In your code, you are getting both sheets as blobs and zipping them??

The easiest fix it is to change `for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {` to `for (var i=0; i<1; i++) {` so it only gets the first tab and zips it.

**UPDATE** Based on comments.

```
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {

    var email = ""; // Enter the required email address here

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("**********"); // Enter the name of the sheet here

    var subject = "PDF generated from spreadsheet " + ss.getName();

    var body = "\n Attached is a PDF copy of the sheet " + sheet.getName() + " in the " + ss.getName() + " spreadsheet.";

    // Base URL
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

    /* Specify PDF export parameters
    From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
     */

    var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
         + '&size=letter' // paper size legal / letter / A4
         + '&portrait=false' // orientation, false for landscape
         + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' // fit to page width, false for actual size
         + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
         + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
         + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
         + '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
            headers : {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        }).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");

    // Uncomment the line below to save the PDF to the root of your drive. 
    //  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(response).setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf")

    if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
            htmlBody : body,
            attachments : [response]
        });
}
```

Comment: So any way to stop it from zipping, so it just sends the PDF please. Regards Alig

Comment: Ok so I have stopped the zip but want to name the file as per the 1st Tab. Currently it names the file as export.pdf

Comment: Hi James, I have included the revised code above below the original code, funilly enough, marked as 'Revised Code'. Many thanks. Al

Comment: Good, no problem. Please click the green tick to accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: This worked for me perfectly to send a recurring email of a particular sheet within my spreadsheet. I'd like to use this to send a reminder for each month. Is there a way to pick the sheet for the previous month to be emailed? Meaning, if I set a schedule to run the script on the 1st of a month, I'd want the sheet from the prior month tab to be sent? Great answer otherwise!

Comment: @user1837608 Ya it's possible, several ways of doing it depending on how the sheets are named. If the sheets had the date in name or number format you could get the current date when the script runs take a month of and use an indexOf() to select the correct sheet.