# Google App Script Email as PDF from Spreadsheet

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, email-attachments

My code below for generate PDF attachment is working fine but they send all data in the spreadsheet.

Anyone can help to send only the specify spreadsheet like my code only sheet"Email" in stead of All sheets ?
Thank you

```js
function SendEmail() {

  try {
    var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=pdf";

    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email')
    var subjectrange = sheet.getRange("A20");
    var subjectdata = subjectrange.getValues();
    var emailranges=sheet.getRange('E14');
    var emaildata=emailranges.getValue();
    var username=ss.getSheetId();
    blob.setName(ss.getName()+ ".pdf");
    var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Send Email Confirmation','Are you sure you want to send this mail for booking request ?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    if(confirm=='ok') {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emaildata, subjectdata, " Attachment file is:  \n"  +subjectdata+ "- \n Kindly reply your booking to this email . \n Thank you - ADS Co., Ltd", {attachments: [blob]}) };} catch (f) {Logger.log(f.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these threads useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/21997924 https://stackoverflow.com/q/44345093/7108653 By the way, when you provide your script, I would like to recommend to show it as a text. By this, the users can easy to copy and test and modify it.

Comment: `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.` [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for post images, i have post code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

If you don't want to export some `sheets` you can [hide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidesheet) them. Furthermore, you can export a `Spreadsheet` with the method [getBlob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getblob). Once you have made the export, you can [undo the hide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showsheet).

### Small code assuming two sheets

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Unwanted Sheet')
sheet.hideSheet()
var blob = ss.getBlob()
blob.setName(ss.getName())
sheet.showSheet()
```

### Full code working with many sheets

```
function exportSheet(sheetName) {    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== sheetName) {
      sheets[i].hideSheet()
    } 
  }
  var blob = ss.getBlob()
  blob.setName(ss.getName())
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].showSheet()
  }
}
```

### Some tips

- You don't have to add `.pdf` to the blob name, it already understand that it is a pdf file and the extension will appear automatically
- You can use [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) service instead of [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail) since it is more versatile and has more functionalities. The main reason to use `MailApp` is using that it doesn’t require the developer to be a Gmail user.

### Reference

- [hideSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidesheet)
- [showSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showsheet)
- [getBlob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getblob)
- [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)
- [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail)